# Sephardic Recordings/Melodies of Asheth Chayil

Tags: sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, music, aishes-chayil

Does anyone have any links or recordings of Asheth Chayil in the Sephardic/Mizrahi tradition? I'm sure there must be some out there, but i'm not having much luck finding any.

Answer (score 2):

My usual source of melodies from various traditions is: http://www.piyut.org.il/english/

For Eshet Chayil they don't have many sephardig/mizrahi recordings. I could find the following: a [Tunisian melody](http://www.piyut.org.il/tradition/english/2889.html?currPerformance=3741) and a [Yeminite melody](http://www.piyut.org.il/tradition/english/454.html?currPerformance=553).

There is a iraqi melody on [youtube](https://youtu.be/4ApvviaSrvc?t=11s) that is close to how I have heard it being sung in my own family

Comment: Close huh? Considering that in all the Sefardi minyanim I've ever been at, people in the same minyan singing along with the hazzan all sing differently than each other, this tune might actually be the same exact one as yours:)